# Shield database size when exposing keys? (without killing performance)

Tags: database

We have a database table that will be 10 million records. We don't want to use auto_increment because that will allow our users to know how many records we have. We don't want to expose that to our competitors. The problem I see is that using UUID or something like that will kill query performance.

for instance, this is a no-no:
http://domain.com/widgets?id=34345

because competitors can crawl the site to determine how many widgets we have. Should this business shielding be handled on the app level, or is it OK to handle it on the database level? What do most people do in this situation? The database we're using is postgres, but I assume the solution is still database agnostic.

Comment: Do the PKs need to be exposed? I view PKs as an *internal artifact* (also a business rule if not surrogate) so step #1 is to review this. As Scott M. Points out a GUID can do this, however, in many cases I'd argue for a surrogate covering GUID (or other nonce, perhaps a pretty name as per Franks answer) key when the particular record needs to be exposed (to anyone "untrusted") and not just replace the PK with a GUID. Of course ... it all depends :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use GUIDs as keys. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029651/fastest-way-in-c-sharp-to-iterate-through-all-guids-possible) to see why it would be OK to do. You may be able to get away with using a subset of the GUID number, but the smaller the bit size, the more likely a collision. A GUID is not overly large and should be able to be stored as a number. The transfer would be 4 times as much for the key, but that is largely irrelevant.

The storage might be about 120 MB more for 10 million rows, but that seems negligible at such a large size. Have you tested the performance of GUIDs and found them lacking?

Comment: I'm not a fan of GUIDs for PKs (although they have some compelling use-cases), but a GUID can be used as an external reference/nonce as a *candidate key* to avoid exposure of the *primary key* (at an arguably small loss of normalization). I would likely suggest a tidied up "half GUID" if the information is ever user-visible... hate working with SharePoint object IDs :(

Comment: What I'm really concerned about is query performance? Is querying 10M rows with a 60 char UUID string going to be slower than querying a 10M row table with an integer ID? Or will the difference be negligible?

Comment: i think you're thinking of GUIDs in the wrong way. It's a 128-bit (16 byte) number. That's much less than 60 chars at 60 bytes. Also, if you do use text you could use an index to find the rows. I honestly have no way of knowing the exact performance implications because I do not have the database, but I think that a 16 byte transfer over the wire vs 4 wouldn't be much of a difference. On the DB side, indexing for text or BLOBs or even a 128 bit number might be possible.

Comment: At my job we have a couple of tables where the primary key is a 36 (not 60) char string that looks like this: "6347a8a8-6296-11e1-8b7f-12313d08f2ab" This is a GUID, correct? The reason I made this question is because when I saw this I thought to myself "Holy hell this has to be way slower than querying by integer PK..."

Answer (score 2):

I use slug based urls where `slug` is unique and therefore indexed field, plus you get nice urls like http://example.com/awesome-blue-widget. You can create slugs by lowercasing the widget name, replacing spaces with hyphens etc. My web framework has an easy `slugify` function for it, that I extended to add an increment on the end if a slug is already taken.

Slugs generally match the pattern `[a-z0-9-]+`. And you can still have your auto-incremented primary key for use in foreign keys in other tables and such without compromising your business data.

Comment: This is a great idea actually because its kind of like GUIDs that you can control. The reason I stayed away from strings is actually because of the searching and comparison aspect, which is generally slower than binary (even 128 bit numbers). I can imagine an index on the text would help though.